# CompileError : command 'C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1 while installing pystan

Tags: python-3.x, gcc, mingw, facebook-prophet, pystan

i'm trying to get pystan to work on Windows 10 in order to use the fbprophet package for time series. I have already installed MinGW, added its directories to my PATH environment variable and tried this piece of code to verify everything is working fine:

```
gcc -dumpversion
ld -v
dllwrap -version
```

which yields these results:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>gcc -dumpversion
6.3.0

C:\WINDOWS\system32>ld -v
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.28

C:\WINDOWS\system32>dllwrap -version
GNU dllwrap (GNU Binutils) 2.28
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or (at your option) any later version.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
```

everything iw working fine to this point.

The problems comes when once in python, i try to execute the following code:

```
import pystan
model_code = 'parameters {real y;} model {y ~ normal(0,1);}'
model = pystan.StanModel(model_code=model_code)
y = model.sampling(n_jobs > 1).extract()['y']
y.mean()  # with luck the result will be near 0
```

for which i'm getting this output:

```
import pystan
model_code = 'parameters {real y;} model {y ~ normal(0,1);}'
model = pystan.StanModel(model_code=model_code)
y = model.sampling(n_jobs > 1).extract()['y']
y.mean()  # with luck the result will be near 0
INFO:pystan:COMPILING THE C++ CODE FOR MODEL anon_model_5944b02c79788fa0db5b3a93728ca2bf NOW.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-941feb69c4c4>", line 3, in <module>
    model = pystan.StanModel(model_code=model_code)

  File "Z:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pystan\model.py", line 313, in __init__
    build_extension.run()

  File "Z:\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
    self.build_extensions()

  File "Z:\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions
    self._build_extensions_serial()

  File "Z:\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 473, in _build_extensions_serial
    self.build_extension(ext)

  File "Z:\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 533, in build_extension
    depends=ext.depends)

  File "Z:\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 574, in compile
    self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)

  File "Z:\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 175, in _compile
    raise CompileError(msg)

CompileError: command 'C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1
```

I have searched on the website prior to posting this question, as well as in other websites, but nothing seems to work for me. I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance